# Getting checkbox selections from HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to iterate over an HTML list containing checkboxes in order to obtain the `id` associated with each checkbox. However, the `forEach()` function on the Javascript I have written gives the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: faculty_deck_list.forEach is not a function`. I am trying to iterate through the IDs as follows:

```
var decks = []; //Store the decks

var faculty_deck_list = document.getElementById('faculty_list').getElementsByTagName('input');

var student_deck_list = document.getElementById('student_list').getElementsByTagName('input');

faculty_deck_list.each(function () {
    decks.push($(this).id);
});

student_deck_list.each(function () {
    decks.push($(this).id);
});
```

I am generating the list with the elements as follows:

```
function populateLists(json) {
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
    //Create a new list element
    var list_item = document.createElement('li'); 
    list_item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Object.values(json)[i].name));

    //Create the checkbox to add to the list element
    var select_checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    select_checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    select_checkbox.id = json[i].deck_ID;

    //Add the checkbox to the list element
    list_item.appendChild(select_checkbox);

    var list_name = (json[i].faculty=='1')?'faculty':'student' + '_list';

    list = document.getElementById(list_name);

    list.append(list_item);
}
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="row" id="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="faculty">
        <h3> Faculty decks </h3>
        <ul id="faculty_list"> </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3> Instructions </h3>
        <p> Select your decks, select front (questions) or back (answers) of the the card and start studying. </p>
        <div>
            <input class="front" type="radio" name="card" id="front" value="Front"> Front &ensp;</input>
            <input class="back" type="radio" name="card" id="back" value="Back"> Back</input>
            <br />
            <br />
            <button id="study"> Start Studying </button>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="student">
        <h3> Student Decks </h3>
        <ul id="student_list"> </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

EDIT:
Javascript function for button click that calls initial function to get selections:

```
$("#study").click(function() {
    alert("CLICKED");
    //Get the selected decks
    var selection = getDeckSelections();

    if(selection.length > 0) {
        //Get the selected side of the card
        var selected_side = $('input[name=side_selection]:checked', '#side_selection_form').val();

        //Store the selected side in session storage
        sessionStorage.setItem("selected_side", selected_side);

        //Ajax call to get cards from database
        $.ajax({
            url: "get_cards.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {selection:JSON.stringify(selection)},
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                json = JSON.parse(data);
                //Store the cards in session storage
                sessionStorage.setItem("cards", JSON.stringify(json));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @jrook Your comment is wrong. By chaining a DOM query onto the results of an earlier one, you limit the depth of the query and get potentially faster results. It's perfectly fine to do this.

Comment: @Scott Marcus, I saw that and removed my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a node list and node lists don't support the `each()` method.

Since you are using JQuery, change your code so that the node list is converted to a JQuery object, which does support `each()`:

```
$(faculty_deck_list).each(function () { ...
```

Comment: Or just `$("#faculty_list input").each(...` and get rid of the node lists.

Comment: @James You wouldn't be getting rid of the node lists (JQuery is just going to create them with standard DOM queries under the hood). JQuery isn't magic.

Comment: When I try this code, after selecting two checkboxes, the loop never runs

Comment: @lillemap I don't see anything in your code that would cause anything to happen when you check a checkbox. I also don't see any checkboxes. You have radio buttons. Where are your event handlers being attached? Your code simply gets the two decks and pushes the elements into new arrays independent of clicking anything.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the checkboxes are part of the `student_list` and `faculty_list` and they are part of the elements dynamically added to the lists from the Javascript function. I have my event handler for the button click set in the same Javascript file

Comment: @lillemap You need to show us all the relevant code. But, during the dynamic creation of the checkboxes, there is no code to set up event handlers for them. If you have that code somewhere else, that code must execute **after** all checkboxes have been created.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I added the event handler for the button, but I do not have event handlers for the checkboxes. I had the checkboxes working when I was using a table instead of a list, but the list was needed for a nicer looking display

Comment: @lillemap if you don't have handlers for the checkboxes, then why would you expect anything to happen when they get clicked?

Comment: @ScottMarcus true, it just makes the code 2 lines shorter and cleaner.  Im aware that jquery does "regular old javascript" under the hood.

Comment: @James Understood, but be careful how you word things. So many rookies think JQuery is a replacement for JavaScript and if they read that a node list can be avoided (instead of the more correct statement that the "explicit" creation of the node list can be avoided), they will think that JQuery is capable of things that JavaScript isn't capable of.

Comment: @ScottMarcus actually I just ran the debugger again and it is getting the decks, and the length of the `decks` array is correct, but it says all the elements are undefined

Comment: @lillemap I know that the decks are being created properly. That's what I indicated 8 comments up from here. That happens as soon as your posted code is encountered. If you inspect the deck objects, you can see what they contain.

Comment: @ScottMarcus According the debugger when the `faculty_deck_list` is populated, it contains the decks with `id` attributes storing the correct integer, but when it goes to add them to the `decks` array it adds them as undefined

Comment: @lillemap When pushing the `id`s into the `decks` array, don't wrap `this` in a JQuery object. The JQuery object doesn't have an `id` property, thus you are getting `undefined`. The lines should be: `decks.push(this.id);` so that you get the `id` of the element you are iterating over at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can also cast your nodelist as an array:

```
var faculty_deck_list = Array.from(document.getElementById('faculty_list').getElementsByTagName('input'))
```

Comment: `Array.from()` is part of ES2015 and is not supported in IE. Better to use: `Array.prototype.slice.call(. . .)`